# Is is possible to set the default values of parameters to be the return of a function? (TCL)

Tags: tcl

In  TCL is it possible to have the default values of parameters be the return value of a function call?

```
proc GetParameterValue { } {
    # calculation for value...
    return value
}

proc TestFunction { {paramVal [GetParameterValue]} } { 
    puts $paramVal
}

TestFunction
```

This results in printing "[GetParameterValue]". Rather than calling the procedure GetParameterValue. Is this possible to do in TCL or do I need to redesign this bit of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default values of parameters can only be constants that you compute at the time of declaration of the procedure (most commonly, they're literals which means you don't need to use `list` to do the construction):

```
proc TestFunction [list [list paramVal [GetParameterValue]]] { 
    ...
}
```

To compute a default value at procedure call time, you have to move the calculation into the body of the procedure. There's a few ways to do the detection of whether to do the calculation, but they come down to three options: using a marker value, getting a count of words in the call, and taking full control of parsing.

### Using a marker value

The trick to this is to find some value that is *really* unlikely to be passed in. For example, if this is to be a piece of text shown to the user, a value with nothing but an ASCII NUL in it is not going to occur; put that in the default then you can tell whether you've got the default and can substitute with what the complex code provides.

```
proc TestFunction {{paramVal "\u0000"}} {
    if {$paramVal eq "\u0000"} {
        set paramVal [GetParameterValue]
    }
    ...
}
```

### Getting a count of words in the call

This relies on the capabilities of the `info level` introspection command. In particular, `info level 0` reports the full list of actual arguments to the current procedure. A bit of counting, and we can can know whether a real value was passed.

```
proc TestFunction {{paramVal "dummy"}} {
    if {[llength [info level 0]] < 2} {
        # Note that the command name itself is always present
        set paramVal [GetParameterValue]
    }
    ...
}
```

It's a totally general approach, so there's no worry about the case where someone provides an unexpected edge case, but it's more complicated when you have multiple arguments as you need to work out how many arguments should be present and so on yourself. That is simple in this case, but gets progressively more difficult as you have more arguments.

### Taking full control of parsing

Ultimately, you can also decide to make a procedure that takes full control of the parsing of its arguments. You do that by giving it a single argument, `args`, and then you can use any approach you want to handle the actual argument list. (I tend to not put the formal argument list in parentheses *in this case only* but that's just my own style.)

```
proc TestFunction args {
    if {[llength $args] == 0} {
        set paramVal [GetParameterValue]
    } elseif {[llength $args] == 1} {
        set paramVal [lindex $args 0]
    } else {
        # IMPORTANT! Let users discover how to use the command!
        return -code error -errorcode {TCL WRONGARGS} \
                "wrong # args: should be \"TestFunction ?paramVal?\""
    }
    ...
}
```

This is currently the only way to do anything truly advanced, e.g., to have optional arguments before mandatory ones. It's also pretty much what you'd have to do in C if you implemented the command there, though adjusted for a different language. The downside is that it is definitely more work than using the built-in basic argument parsing support code provided by the implementation of the `proc` command.

Answer (score 1):

This is meant as a complement to Donal's thorough answer. In the past, I sometimes resorted to the assistance of [`[subst]`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/subst.htm) for computed defaults:

```
proc GetParameterValue {} { return computedDefault }

proc TestFunction {{paramVal [GetParameterValue]}} { 
    puts [subst -novariables $paramVal]
}

TestFunction; # returns "computedDefault"
TestFunction "providedValue"
TestFunction {$test}
```

This avoids the need for (implementing) full control over arguments, and is piggybacking onto the built-in argument handler. It also allows for using anonymous procs rather than explicitly named ones for computing the defaults:

```
proc TestFunction {{paramVal "[apply {{} { return computedValue }}]"}} {
    puts [subst -novariables ${paramVal}]
}

TestFunction; # returns "computedDefault"
TestFunction "providedValue"
TestFunction {$test}
```

It goes without saying that there are also some assumptions behind, which turn into important restrictions depending on one's application case:

- You must keep some discipline in using brackets for the defaults in the argument lists, and placing `[subst]` at the usage sites of the argument variable.
- It assumes that you have some control over the arguments, or that you can guarantee that certain special-purpose characters are not valid members of the arguments' value domain.

Watch:

```
TestFunction {[xxx]}
```

throws

```
invalid command name "xxx"
```

and must be sanitized to

```
TestFunction {\[xxx\]}
```